# Seperate Billing in AWS Account for two different EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, billing

I have two EC2 instances in a single AWS account. Both are running for different application services. Now, I want to make billing separate for that particular account. So, I can get the exact spent and charges for the applications and can manage my account as per that for separate accounting purposes.

Is it possible? If not, then can anyone suggest me a better way to achieve this?

I'm planning to handle the different AWS accounts for both services. But, it will be hard to manage so, I can't prefer that option.

For more, In Google Cloud, they're providing to handle different billing accounts within the same google cloud account. So, I think this concept might be available on AWS also.

Thanks in advance for any little bit of help or suggestion.

Comment: Have a look at Cost Categories https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/create-cost-categories.html maybe?

Answer (score 2):

You can't get separate bills for different sets of resources within the same AWS account. However, you can filter out the costs for different sets of resources using tags. By using a distinct tag (or set of tags) in the resources you allocate to each application, you can get a breakdown of the cost for each application in billing reports and cost explorer. See the documentation for details and steps on how to set it up - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/cost-alloc-tags.html

I believe it's the same with Google Cloud as well - although you can have multiple billing accounts within your google account (the hierarchy in GC is different to AWS, and an AWS account is more similar to a GC project than a GC account), a project within your account must have one billing account and does not support multiples.

Comment: Then what is the best approach to separate billing for different services?

Comment: There's no way to do that. You can only get the AWS monthly bill down to account level. You'll have to deploy your two applications in two AWS accounts to get that. If you want to keep both in one account, you'll have to manage with billing reports filtered by tags.

Answer (score 0):

By this -

> Now, I want to make billing separate for that particular account.

do you mean you already have 2 different AWS accounts? If yes, you can get billing details as per account if they become part of same Organization. Check [AWS Organizations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_introduction.html) docs for more info.

With Orgs, you can view bills of different accounts from one account itself if it is part of org. Also your accounts get discounts for services.

Comment: No. I have only one AWS account. But, in that, I have 2 EC2 instances. And I want to make separate billing for those two EC2 instances within the same account.

Comment: Then tagging is way forward. You can use method suggested above or have a look at cost categories [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/manage-cost-categories.html). Then you can proceed with whichever one is helpful for you.

Comment: Will it give me a separate invoice or not?

Comment: No separate invoice.  But you can filter the generated bills based on tags.